# Example of topological spaces with continuous bijections that are not homotopy equivalent

Tags: general-topology, homotopy-theory

In one of the books on algebraic topology (I don't remember exactly which one) there was an exercise to build an example of two topological spaces having two continuous bijections between them which are **not** homotopy equivalent. To be honest, this exercise confuses me a little because, as I understand, each pair of homeomorphic spaces is homotopy equivalent by construction. On the other hand, the existence of bijective continuous mapping between spaces automatically provides their homeomorphism (correct me if I'm wrong). Thus, in this logic, if we have two continuous bijections between topological spaces this will inevitably lead to the homotopy equivalence between them. I guess, however, that there is a simple counterexample related to the discrete topologies which breaks such a reasoning (see, for example, this: [Is a bijective homotopy equivalence with bijective homotopy inverse a homeomorphism?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/603026/is-a-bijective-homotopy-equivalence-with-bijective-homotopy-inverse-a-homeomorph)), but I have certain difficulties in discovering it. Is there any suggestion?

Comment: The two continuous bijections will not be inverse to each other.  So they could fail to be homeomorphisms.

Comment: Are you asking that the two _continuous bijections_ not be homotopy equivalent, or that the two _spaces_ not be homotopy equivalent? Both are possible, but they'll probably require different examples.

Comment: Initial exercise asks about _spaces_, not mappings.

Comment: @GEdgar, thanks. So, it only remains to build such spaces that any continuous bijection from one to another has discontinuous inverse mapping.

Comment: @AlfredRutkowski More is needed if you want the spaces to have different homotopy types.

Comment: And even if these maps are not homotopy equivalences, we need to show that also no other map is a homotopy equivalence.

Comment: Yes, all this is meant, but I cannot figure out how to reach that so far.

Answer (score 4):

The interval $[0,1)$ admits a continuous bijection to the circle (use $\exp(i 2\pi t)$ as your map). But the two spaces are not homotopy equivalent since the circle is not simply connected.

Edit: If you want to have more than one continuous bijection, just compose my map with a rotation of the circle.