# Continuously bijective but not homotopy equivalent.

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

Give an example of topological spaces $X$,$Y$ with bijective continuous maps between them(so 2 maps in total!), such that $X$ is not homotopy equivalent to $Y$.Be aware of the theorem stating that bijective continuous map from compact space to Hausdorff space must be a homeomorphism. There are also examples such that $f$ and $g$ don't provide a homotopy equivalence, but still the spaces are.

P.S. The problem has already been asked 2 years ago, but there is no satisfactory answer: [Example of topological spaces with continuous bijections that are not homotopy equivalent](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1337620/201204)

Comment: Why do you not find the answer there satisfactory?

Comment: I don't understand the downvotes. The answer there provides just one function from first space to second, but I asked for "functions", so I need one more function from second space to the first. Please read more carefully. Thank you.

Comment: The inverse of that map is not continuous

Comment: I retract my downvote. Still, it would be great if you furnished your thoughts on the problem.